# How to customise keyboard shortucts in Nemo 5.2.4 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, nemo

On one of the last versions of Nemo I was able to switch tabs by pressing `Ctrl`+`Tab`, but now in Nemo 5.2.4 it's set to be `Ctrl`+`PgUp`/`PgDn`. This is not good for me because I'm on a laptop and it's much harder to press it. Does anyone know a way to change the default Nemo keyboard shortcuts? Thanks!

Comment: This example on ArchWiki that shows how to map "Open in terminal" to a shortcut maybe will be useful for a more general key remapping in Nemo, as well.: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nemo#Set_keyboard_shortcut_for_%22Open_in_terminal%22

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings -> keyboards -> keyboards shortcuts. there you will find all sort of keyboard customisation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't answer my question. I wanted to know how to change keyboard shorcuts in Nemo. Thanks anyways.

Comment: please read the question before answering. global keyboard shortcuts will not help

Comment: also, none of that applies to Nemo - it uses the term Preferences, not Settings, and has no sub-section for Keyboards